# Jfreechart - can we set a shape for a datapoint in StackedAreaChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using Jfreechart to make a stacked area chart. I am using the class StackedXYAreaChart.

I wanted to know if we could draw shapes at data points for the StackedAreaChart, (it a line chart we can denote each data point by setting the SetSeriesShapes()).

The method setSeriesShape() doesn't seem to work. Anyone have any idea ?

Here's what I have tried till now (Please do not comment that I have an empty dataset. I am plotting a dynamic graph and the series would be filled later ):

```
 incomingData = new TimeTableXYDataset();
final JFreeChart incomingDataChart = ChartFactory.createStackedXYAreaChart(
            "Chart", "Time", "Payload (In Bytes)", incomingData, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
    final StackedXYAreaRenderer renderChart = new StackedXYAreaRenderer();
    renderChart.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.decode("#339900"));
    renderChart.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.decode("#CC9933"));
    renderChart.setSeriesPaint(2, Color.decode("#33CCFF"));
    renderChart.setSeriesPaint(3, Color.decode("#FF6600"));
    renderChart.setSeriesShape(0, new Ellipse2D.Double(-3, -3, 10, 10));
    renderChart.setSeriesShape(1, new Ellipse2D.Double(-3, -3, 10, 10));
    renderChart.setSeriesShape(2, new Ellipse2D.Double(-3, -3, 10, 10));
    renderChart.setSeriesShape(3, new Ellipse2D.Double(-3, -3, 10, 10));
    incomingDatachart.getPlot().setRenderer(renderChart);
```

Comment: `StackedXYAreaRenderer#setSeriesShape()` works for me; please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: @trashgod - The area region is replaced by a line which covers the area chart. I anyway figured out my answer. The solution is :

StackedXYAreaRenderer renderer = new StackedXYAreaRenderer(StackedXYAreaRenderer.AREA_AND_SHAPES);

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the type of the [StackedXYAreaRenderer](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/StackedXYAreaRenderer.html#StackedXYAreaRenderer-int-) to be "shapes and lines".  That renderer doesn't show the shapes by default.

```
StackedXYAreaRenderer renderer = new StackedXYAreaRenderer(StackedXYAreaRenderer.SHAPES_AND_LINES);
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured the solution out : Use the Statement

```
StackedXYAreaRenderer renderChart = new StackedXYAreaRenderer(StackedXYAreaRenderer.AREA_AND_SHAPES);
```

Then use,

```
renderChart.setSeriesShape(index, Shape);
```